# Slow android app installation even when not using emulator

Tags: android, installation

Everywhere I look I can only find questions about how slow the emulator is.

I'm running my app on a real android device. The app has several short animations and totals around 63MB storage. I understand that the more space the app uses the longer the installation will take, but it still takes 3 to 4 minutes to install and run every time.

I'm debugging through USB 2.0 and would expect far better transfer speeds.

I also tried copying a video from my android device to my computer (also via USB), which also took up about 60MB of space, and it took over a minute -- I seemed to get about 1MB/s upload speed.

Are these speeds expected, or should they be faster?

Comment: 63 MB is fairly large for an app, remember it is transferring and installing not just transferring, the install is proably taking up most of this, copying over lots of images etc maybe finding a way to reduce the size of the images your using would be a solution

Comment: For debugging and development, consider stripping the resources that are not for your device, I.e. If you have an xhdpi device don't include xxhdpi (etc) resources in your dev build (you want to keep them for the test builds though).

Comment: I am excellent with storage and memory management in that I only include the resources necessary. Note that the animations are not series of images, but .avi files rendered with Vitamio. This is what is taking up the storage. I also just found that sometimes restarting my android device will speed up times dramatically (to less than 1 minute), but not always. The behavior is very erratic and unpredictable.

Comment: It is difficult to compare apples to apples. However, my book is available as an APK. Version 6.7's APK is 25.5MB. It takes 10-15 seconds to install on a Nexus 4. Try a different USB cable, and try a different device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do believe it is a device issue, because, as I said, rebooting will occasionally fix the issue.

Comment: Available memory is usually the problem.

Comment: I'd believe so if not for the fact that rebooting the device only works half of the time.

Comment: Different USB cable helped me with that issue.